# Char pointer without square brackets

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I got problem with char pointer.
I know that I can make something like this:

```
char *pointer="something";
```

but how I can exchange the content of it?

I dont want to use square brackets, I can use only curly(round) brackets.

Comment: Research: pointer arithmetic

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan abstraction. You have some one else write (so it isn't your code) a header with `#define man main` then you `#include`... rats. Another 'i'.

Comment: _"I dont want to use square brackets, I can use only curly(round) brackets."_ y'wot

Answer (score 3):

The only answer is: You can't.

A string literal is actually a *read-only* array, you can't modify it. That's why you normal declare pointers to string literals as `const`:

```
const char *pointer = "foo";
```

You need to declare an array yourself and initialize it if you want to modify the contents:

```
char str[100] = "foo";
```

Or, since you are programming in C++, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
std::string str = "foo";
```

Using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) you also don't have to worry about overflowing the array if you want to insert more characters.